# What does "alloca" stand for?

Tags: history, etymology

The `alloca()` function allocates memory in the stack frame of the caller. What did `alloca` originally stand for? Are there any sources regarding the etymology of the name?

Comment: This kind of question might be a better fit for [retrocomputing.se]?

Comment: @amon I wasn't sure... Answers to [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97786/where-to-ask-questions-about-computer-science-history) suggest Software Engineering, Retrocomputing or Computer Science.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some sleuthing in historic sources, and it seems that the "a" in "alloca" stands for "automatic", as in automatically freed.

The [GNU man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) says:

```
There is evidence that the alloca() function appeared in 32V,
PWB, PWB.2, 3BSD, and 4BSD.  There is a man page for it in
4.3BSD.  Linux uses the GNU version.
```

Linked from [this commit message](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-man/msg21150.html) I found archives of UNIX/32V and PWB/UNIX sources, each of which contains an `alloca.s` assembly file:

##### **`32v/usr/src/libc/sys/alloca.s`**

```
# like alloc, but automatic
# automatic free in return

.globl  _alloca
_alloca:
    .word   0x0000
    subl2   4(ap),sp    # crude allocation
    movl    16(fp),r1   # pc
    movq    8(fp),ap    # new (old) ap and fp
    bicl2   $3,sp       # 4-byte align
    addl2   $7*4,sp     # reuse space of mscp
    movl    sp,r0       # return value
    jmp     (r1)        # funny return
```

##### **`spencer_pwb/sys/source/s4/util/alloca.s`**

```
/   wdptr = alloca(nbytes);
/ like alloc, but automatic
/ automatic free upon return from calling function

.globl _alloca
_alloca:
    mov (sp)+,r1    / return
    mov (sp),r0     /count
    inc r0
    bic $1,r0       / round up
    sub r0,sp       / take core
    mov sp,r0
    tst (r0)+       / returned value; will generate
                / a memory fault if there isn't enough core
    jmp (r1)
.data
    <@(#)alloca 1.1\0>
```

I believe the `alloc` function referenced would be a predecessor of the modern `malloc`, based on this function definition in PWB:

##### **`spencer_pwb/sys/source/s4/alloc.c`**

```
/*      alloc - old-style memory allocator
 *      returns -1 on fail rather than 0
*/
alloc(n)
{
        register p;
        p = malloc(n);
        return(p?p:-1);
}
```